# Preparing annual working scale week by week without working two weeks in a row

Tags: php, mysql, sql

There are 6 judges and 4 specialists to meet our foreign guests in our academy. 4 specialists are working with 6 judges to help them. In `parent_id` column, each specialist that has been shown to work with judges. I want to prepare an annual working scale week by week. So firstly I prepared a user table shown in the below capture. (`users` table)[image: Users]
Judges and specialists should not be assigned two weeks in a row I want. So I coded a foreach loop and created 52 weeks. Later I inserted judges into it name by name. Here is my codes.

```
$judge_list = array();
$judge_ids = array();
 // Retrieve all results from users table which mission is judge.
$judges = $db->get_results("SELECT * FROM users WHERE mission='judge'");
// How many times we must repeat to reach 52? Because a year has got 52 weeks.
$repeat =  ceil(52/count($judges)); 
// Until it reaches min. 52 returns first names and last names of the judges. 
for ($i=1; $i<=$repeat; $i++) foreach ($judges as $judge) $judge_list[] = $judge["first_name"] . ' ' . $judge["last_name"];
// Until it reaches min. 52 returns id numbers of the judges. 
for ($i=1; $i<=$repeat; $i++) foreach ($judges as $judge) $judge_ids[] = $judge["id"];
// Make a new array which contains judge's names, surnames and ids. Than get first 52.
$array = array_slice(@array_map(null, $judge_ids, $judge_list), 0, 52);
// Before insert new datas, truncate table.
$db->truncate("scale");
$x = 1;
// And last, insert into annual working scale table.
foreach ($array as $judg){
    $db->insert("scale", array('week' => $x, 'judge_id' => $judg[0], 'judge_name' => $judg[1]));
    $x++;
}
```

And it was figured below capture. (`scale` table) [image: Scale]
Than I created a specialists table and filled data from users like this.

```
// Retrieve all results from users table which mission is specialist.
$specialists = $db->get_results("SELECT * FROM users WHERE mission='specialist'");
// Before insert new datas, truncate table.
$db->truncate("project_specialist");
// Loop all specialists.
foreach ($specialists as $specialist) {
    $judges = explode($specialist["parent_id"], ',');
    foreach ($judges as $judge) $db->insert("specialists", array('judge_id' => $judge, 'specialist_id' => $specialist["id"], 'specialist_name' => $specialist["first_name"].' '.$specialist["last_name"])); 
}
```

It as figured like this. (`specialist` table)[image: Specialists]

Now here is the problem: I want to update `scale` table with the specialists. The specialists should not work two weeks in a row. But I did not manage. Please could you help me, how can I code sql query?

Comment: What SQL statements have you tried?

Comment: I am going to add tomorrow morning. Now I shut down my computer.

Comment: Question is unclear. What do you mean  "two weeks in a row"? Make your work schedule first.

Comment: Sorry for my English. It is not my native languge. For example if a specialist is assigned in 3. week, we must not assign in 4. week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is can be solved by a simple enumeration and modulo operator. This approach doesn't take into account other factors like frequency of work for specialists meeting a certain level, but this is a start to solve the problem, which you were seemingly approaching by way of arbitrary enumeration anyway. This query returns 1 row per week (1-52), and returns a single judge and a single specialist linked to that judge for each week (EDIT: and is guaranteed to not repeat the same person two weeks in a row on either level). This makes use of two user variables that are incremented independently to enumerate the persons in question, then joins them to the selection of week numbers by way of the modulo operator (and the parent_id = judge id for specialists). The [SQLFiddle example here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5e4d3/144) shows the results. The status in the where clause and the count used in the inner queries are built to handle data that is larger or smaller than the sample you gave, and will automatically adjust scheduling based on the addition or deletion (or non-'active' status) of people in this table. This is on the presumption of the existence of a table (weeks) which has 52 rows, where id runs from 1 to 52. The encasing and final left join are for the odd case where the current judge and the specialist sequence don't match, and the first sequence matching fails to select a specialist, so we make another run at it and limit the second results to not in either the preceding or following weeks. Under test bench conditions, this provided 52 rows with a specialist for each row, no one specialist or judge working two weeks in a row. Schedule may need to be tweaked somewhat as, for example, specialist ID 11 doesn't get scheduled to work as often because of the aforementioned oddity.

```
select WeekNum, JudgeID, Judge_first_name, Judge_last_name, coalesce(SpecialistID, s.id) AS SpecialistID, coalesce(Specialist_first_name, s.first_name) AS Specialist_first_name, coalesce(Specialist_last_name, s.last_name) AS Specialist_last_name
from (
    select w.id AS WeekNum, j.id AS JudgeID, j.first_name as Judge_first_name, j.last_name as Judge_last_name
      , s.id As SpecialistID, s.first_name as Specialist_first_name, s.last_name as Specialist_last_name
    from weeks w
      inner join (
        select @judgeNum:=@judgeNum + 1 AS JudgeNum, id, first_name, last_name, (select count(id) from users where mission = 'judge' and status = 'active') AS NumJudges
        from users
          join (select @judgeNum:=0) n
        where mission = 'judge'
          and status = 'active'
      ) j on (w.id % j.NumJudges) + 1 = j.JudgeNum
      left join (
        select SpecialistNum, s.id, cast(substring_index(substring_index(parent_id,',',w.id),',',-1) AS unsigned) AS JudgeID, first_name, last_name, NumSpecialists
        from (
            select @specialistNum:=@specialistNum + 1 AS SpecialistNum, id, parent_id, first_name, last_name, (select count(id) from users where mission = 'specialist' and status = 'active') AS NumSpecialists
            from users
              join (select @specialistNum:=0) n
            where mission = 'specialist'
              and status = 'active'
          ) s
          join weeks w on w.id <= length(s.parent_id) - length(replace(s.parent_id,',','')) + 1
      ) s on s.JudgeID = j.id
        and (w.id % s.NumSpecialists) + 1 = s.SpecialistNum
    ) t
    left join (
        select *
        from users u
        where mission = 'specialist'
            and status = 'active'
    ) s on t.specialistID IS NULL
        AND s.parent_id rlike '/[^\d]' + t.JudgeID + '[^\d]/'
where s.id is null or s.id not in (
    select c.id As SpecialistID
    from weeks w2
        inner join (
            select @judgeNum:=@judgeNum + 1 AS JudgeNum, id, first_name, last_name, (select count(id) from users where mission = 'judge' and status = 'active') AS NumJudges
            from users
              join (select @judgeNum:=0) n
            where mission = 'judge'
                and status = 'active'
        ) j on (w2.id % j.NumJudges) + 1 = j.JudgeNum
        left join (
            select SpecialistNum, c.id, cast(substring_index(substring_index(parent_id,',',w3.id),',',-1) AS unsigned) AS JudgeID, first_name, last_name, NumSpecialists
            from (
                select @specialistNum:=@specialistNum + 1 AS SpecialistNum, id, parent_id, first_name, last_name, (select count(id) from users where mission = 'specialist' and status = 'active') AS NumSpecialists
                from users
                  join (select @specialistNum:=0) n
                where mission = 'specialist'
                  and status = 'active'
              ) c
              join weeks w3 on w3.id <= length(c.parent_id) - length(replace(c.parent_id,',','')) + 1
        ) c on c.JudgeID = j.id
        and (w2.id % c.NumSpecialists) + 1 = c.SpecialistNum
    where w2.id in (t.WeekNum-1, t.WeekNum+1)
)
order by weeknum
;
```

Comment: Firstly thank you very much. I think, I could not find googling. Of course, I did not find. And sorry... I want to award my bounty but I came across an error like this: "You may award your bounty in 4 hours.". But there is no information about this situation in the page http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty. If you respond again, I will try to award. Sorry for time differ.

Comment: And if I want to use this SQL in .Net to retrive data from MS Access, is it work? I tried but I got errors. I did not understand.

Comment: Your question is tagged mysql, thus I was using MySQL syntax. JetSQL, the engine behind MS Access, is rather different from the other dialects of SQL out there. Is your question mis-tagged as MySQL? Should it be tagged MS-Access?

Comment: Firstly, I coded PHP & MySQL. But later, after I saw possibility,  thank you very much again, I decided to create same structure on the Ado.Net, (C# & MS Access (.accdb)). I do not know, both platforms (MySQL & MsSQL) requires different SQL structure.

Comment: I did not pay attention when I saw that the code you gave works fine. But query is wrong. Because 3., 10., 15., 22., 27., 34., 39., 46., 51. weeks are not listed. Could you help me?

Comment: SQLFiddle is currently down. My guess is that there is an issue with the inner join of the Specialists, who, for example, if the given # does not have a link to the current judge, will cause the row to be eliminated. When SQLFiddle comes back online and I can get tot he demo data again, I can adapt it to be more fluid.

Comment: I tried over inner join of the Specialists who does not have a link to the current judge, but result is gloomy.

Comment: I worked on it a bit the other day, but have an idea this morning that should work. Stay tuned.

Comment: The edit returns 52 rows and can serve to insert into a table as a base. The schedule should be tweaked from the query results. per my updated description.

Comment: Thank you very much. Four specialists are working in year 18, 17, 8 and 8 weeks. But I think we can edit manually. :)